# On GitHub (gist) what is the star button used for?

Tags: github

What does the star button do on GitHub's gist section?

For example: https://gist.github.com/1372818

I have three buttons in the headline, they are:

> edit - download - (un)star

With the last one changing from star to unstar as I click on it.

At first I thought it was an upvote system. But I can **star** my own code, and it doesn't mention some star appearing elsewhere.

The next idea was a favorites icon or a bookmark. I can select "starred gists" but the page came up even before I starred it.

The GitHub help didn't have anything about "star", and the search box is for searching in code and in pages - not to search the help pages of github::gist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's for you to keep track of gists that have made you smile or caught you off guard and you want to have a list of them stored at Github.

It is just like a bookmark system. You mark a star on a gist you find interesting or like and then you can find them at a glance under your account at [starred gists](https://gist.github.com/starred).

The link to your starred gists will be there for your account, but if you have nothing, it will simply prompt you to create a new gist. One that you may star yourself.

Comment: I starred a gist but it's not appearing for me... not sure if this functionality is broken, or changed. Right now I see a list of random gists that I have not even looked at before.

Comment: same, i starred a gist thinking i'd be able to find it later and now it's awol. there's nothing but random gists at that link.

Comment: It's 2023 and the link to https://gist.github.com/starred still provides recently active starred gists (by anyone) and doesn't do what you'd expect (filtering down to your starred gists.). But the path suggested in the other answer https://gist.github.com/<username>/starred does work like you'd want. Why do they hide it in the user icon menu?!

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is either wrong or outdated.

Gists that you have starred are at this url: `https://gist.github.com/{Username}/starred`

So, my starred gists for example are located at https://gist.github.com/Pamblam/starred

You can also get to this page by going to the gists page (gist.github.com) clicking on your profile image in the top right then clicking "Starred gists"

Thanks to Steve @slgraff at Github for this info.

Comment: Please note that "above" has no real meaning in answers, since they can be sorted in a number of ways and, even in the default sort, votes change over time. Better to link to the answer to which you're referring.

Comment: Thanks but considering this is the first answer in more than half a decade I think readers can deduce, even if not, it's not essential info.